# keep only specific values from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Hi I have the following `dataset`

```
 column1 column2  
0 Paul       xx       
1 John       xx      
2 Paul       xx      
3 John       xx       
4 John       bb       
5 George     bb       
6 Paul       xx
7 john       xx
```

What I want is to keep only the `values` of `column2` that appears more than `two` times along with the corresponding `value` of `column1`

So I want the following:

```
  column1 column2  
0 Paul       xx       
1 John       xx      
2 Paul       xx      
3 John       xx            
4 Paul       xx
5 john       xx
```

I try the following but this code cannot return the `values` of `column1`

```
def get_cmd_more_than_2(dfb):
  cmd_more_than_2 = dfb['column1'].value_counts()[dfb['column1'].value_counts() > 2]
  return cmd_more_than_1

dfb = get_cmd_more_than_2(dfb)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just one line of code:

```
df = df[df.column2.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

**Full reproducible code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'column1': ['Paul', 'John', 'Paul', 'John', 'John', 'George', 'Paul', 'john'],
    'column2': ['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'bb', 'gg', 'xx', 'xx']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[df.column2.duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index(drop=True)

#   column1 column2
#0  Paul    xx
#1  John    xx
#2  Paul    xx
#3  John    xx
#4  Paul    xx
#5  john    xx
```

Comment: thank you. I make a little modification on the initial set of data.  Now row 4-5 have the same value. Sorry for this

Comment: If this helps, accept it as the answer.